# Calculating limit of a complicated function

Tags: calculus, limits

I want a formal way to calculate limit of this expression (which I encountered in a physics course) as $T\to 0$ and as $T\to \infty$. Here $\beta=\frac{1}{k_B T}$. I have tried and found that for $T=0$, it is $0/0$ form but then differentiating it makes it more complicated.

$$f(T)=\frac{-hN\tanh(\beta h)+Nk_BT\log(2\cosh(\beta h))}{T}$$which by replacing $\beta$ with $1/(k_B T)$ gives
$$f(T)=\frac{-hN\tanh( h/(k_B T))+Nk_BT\log(2\cosh(h/(k_B T)))}{T}$$

Comment: You should use *either* $T$ *or* $\beta$ in your expression, not both as it will make it clearer. Also, $\tanh x \to1$ as $x \to\infty$

Comment: @danimal question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=h\beta$, and $y=e^{-2x}$.  When $x\to\infty$, $xy\to0$
$$f(x)=\frac{N}{k_B}\left(-x\tanh(x)+\log(2\cosh(x))\right)\\
=\frac{N}{k_B}\left(-x\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}+\log(e^x+e^{-x})\right)\\
=\frac{N}{k_B}\left(-x\frac{1-y}{1+y}+x+\log(1+y)\right)\\
=\frac{N}{k_B}\left(-x+\frac{2xy}{1+y}+x+\log(1+y)\right)
\to0\text{ as }x\to\infty\text{ and }T\to0^+
$$
Also, as $T\to\infty$, then $x\to0$, $y\to1$, so $f(x)\to (N\log 2)/k_B$